# C# selectionchanged item implementing database error in Visual Studio with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio

I'm trying to change my application to implement a database. I've managed to change most but this code is not working for me:

```
private void FleetList_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (btnRmvFleet != true)
    /*{
        Cars = ((Fleet)FleetList.SelectedItem).Car;
        CarList.ItemsSource = Cars;   // what the code was before I changed it
        boxFirstCar.DataContext = Cars;
    }*/
    {
        db.Cars = ((Fleet)FleetList.SelectedItem).Car;
        CarList.ItemsSource = db.Cars;       // how I'm trying to make it work                   
        boxFirstCar.DataContext = db.Cars;

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    else
    {
        btnRmvFleet = false;
    }
}
```

I get an error at

```
((Fleet)FleetList.SelectedItem).Car;
```

I tried to add database to some things but I must be missing something..

Thanks for your help in advance!

Screenshot of the error:

[*LINK*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WCh1.png)

Ask for whatever more you need. Just know I'm not very experienced in stackoverflow or C#

About my code:

in every fleet there are different cars. Therefore I want my app to change the cars list to the cars of the fleet selected. So when you select another fleet, you will get to see the cars from that fleet.

The cars and the fleets are in a (code-first) database.

I use Entity Framework and I am trying to change the list of cars showing in my application. When you select another fleet, it should show different cars.

**Just to clarify, the code between /* */ works! But now i am trying to implement the database.**

Comment: Please edit the question to include the entire exception detail.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Give us something to work with.

Comment: Errors contain text, not images. On SO we prefer the errors in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry i don't know what to do to define my problem. i was hoping someone would see my code and would think "oh he forgot that bit"

Comment: Explain what you are trying to do in that line of code. You certainly do not want to set the value of your `Cars` DbSet.

Comment: @kentoB Based on the context and naming convention, and assuming you are using EntityFramework, what I understood is you are trying to assign a single object `Car` to collection `Cars`. Instead what happens if you try: `db.Cars.Add( ((Fleet)FleetList.SelectedItem).Car)` ? Also should save changes before you reload them: `db.SaveChanges()`.

Comment: @SivaGopal Thanks for your reaction. I indeed use EntityFramework. But i am not trying to add a car to cars. i am trying to change the list of cars showing in my application. When you select another fleet, it should show different cars.

Comment: @kentoB May be you can try what I suggested and let me know, if you still see any issue.

Comment: Re-reading your question I am not sure what you are trying to do. You appear to try and *save* the cars of the selected fleet to the dabase - you don't need that

Comment: let me put it this way: the code between the /* */ is the code that was there first. but when i made the cars and fleets get and set from the db i got errors at all "Cars" in that pice of code. then i tried to add database references to it (pice of code below /* */), but i could not get it to work.